# How to read contact one by one record from .vcf file

Tags: android, contacts, vcf-vcard

In my application i want to read the .vcf file which is stored in my sdcard then after i want to store that contact in my phonebook.

Comment: Have a look through the "Related" questions and the righthand side of this page - there's more than likely something in there that answers your question.

Comment: In my contact backup application i want to backup a contact in a .vcf file its done very well but now i want to read the .vcf file which is store in my sdcard folder to restore them in it to its original place.and also refers so many links but i cant fine proper answer so i ask related question @Simon:,@MH:.